# Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql

alguien me podria decir porque me marca este error en mi codigo?

> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\PROYECTOFINALLP4\registrobd.php on line 61*

Trato de hacer un registro y que se guarde en una base de datos que he creado, les dejo el codigo:

```
<?php

$host = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "root";
$password = "";

$conectar = mysql_connect ($host, $user, $password);
mysql_select_db("proyectofinallp4", $conectar);

$id = $_POST["id"];
$nombre =  $_POST["nombre"];
$password = $_POST["password"];


$consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios id = '$id', nombre = '$nombre', password = '$password'";
$query = mysql_query ($consulta, $conectar);
$resultado = mysql_fetch_row ($query); //ESTA ES LA LINEA 61


if ($query == null) {
echo "<center><h1>ERROR AL REGISTRAR</h1></center>" . mysql_error();
}
else
{
echo "<center><h1>USUARIO REGISTRADO EXITOSAMENTE</h1></center>";
}
?>
```

Comment: antes de ejecutar `mysql_fetch_row` podrias comprobar que el query no tenga errores con `if($query)`

Comment: probando con la funcion mysql_error();
me sale lo sig:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'id = '2', nombre = 'invitado', password = '456'' at line 1

Comment: Te recomiendo que cambies el titulo de la pregunta para que sea mas entendible. Podrías utilizar este: ¿Como realizar un INSERT INTO en MySQL?.

Comment: Emanuel me alegro que hayas encontrado una respuesta a tu pregunta. Te recomiendo muchísimo que puedas [ver esta otra pregunta en este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php/53280#53280) para que puedas aprender como hacer mucho mas seguro tu código, y que dejes de usar la clase mysql que es totalmente insegura. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes arreglar el query.

```
$consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios SET id = '$id', nombre = '$nombre', password = '$password'";
$query = mysql_query ($consulta, $conectar);
```

Fijate que utilizo **SET** después del nombre de la tabla.

Segundo es eliminar el `mysql_fetch_row` ya que este no es utilizado en este tipo de comandos.

Espero te haya sido de utilidad.

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS POR SU RESPUESTA, ME SIRVIO !!!!
EN SERIO SE LO AGRADEZCO BASTANTE, SALUDOS!!! :D :D

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en que `mysql_fetch_row()` espera una variable de tipo `resource`. Tu le estás pasando como parámetro la variable `$query`. Ésta toma el valor de retorno de la consulta que estás ejecutando.

Según la documentación de PHP si ejecutas una consulta de tipo: SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN, entre otras, con mysql_query la función te regresa una variable de tipo `resource`. Pero si es de tipo INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc; te devuelve una variable booleana.

Documentación:

- [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php)
- [mysql_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, la verdad como podras darte cuenta soy nuevo en esto, podrias decirme que como corregirlo? lo agradeceria bastante!!!

Comment: Perdón por tardar en responder.Si lo que quieres es únicamente ingresar el registro a la base de datos no es necesaria esa línea. En cambio, si quieres mostrar el registro que acabas de ingresar es necesario hacer una consulta nueva.

Answer (score -1):

`mysql_fetch_row` solo funciona con consultas tipo `select`, no con insert into.

No se en realidad para que necesitas esa linea

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, entonces sugieres que la elimine?